# Ошибка is not a function javascript

Tags: javascript

Пожалуйста объясните почему код на JS, приведенный ниже, выдает ошибку:
TypeError: a.toFixed is not a function.

Код:

```
var a = Math.sqrt(5).toFixed(2);
var b = a.toFixed(2);
alert(a);
```

Comment: Переменная `a` у вас какого типа? А перед началом второй строки?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что, `a` будет хранить значение строки `"2.24"`, а метод `toFixed` не принадлежит строкам.

По шагам:

- `Math.sqrt(5) // 2.23606797749979`
- `a = Math.sqrt(5).toFixed(2) // "2.24"`
- `b = a.toFixed(2) // TypeError...`

Код без ошибок:

```
var a = Math.sqrt(5);
var b = a.toFixed(2);
alert(b);
```